# Unclosed Character Class (Regex)

Tags: java, regex

So, I have this semi-complex regex that is searching for all text in between two strings, then replacing it.

My search regex for this is:

```
(jump *[A-Z].*)(?:[^])*?([A-Z].*:)
```

This gives an Unclosed Character Class on the final closing bracket, which I have been struggling to solve. The regex seems to work as intended on RegexR (http://regexr.com/?38k63)

Could anyone provide some help or insight?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is at here:

```
(jump *[A-Z].*)(?:[^])*?([A-Z].*:)
                   ^
```

In character class `^` is still a special character. It usually negates other characters when you place there. So escape it with `\\` in Java.

Comment: Aha, thank you! Eclipse and many other "verifiers" weren't giving me exact locations so I was rather confused.

Comment: I believe `^` is a special character only when it's the *first* thing in the character class, like it is here.  `[a^]` will match either `a` or `^`.

Comment: @ajb Yes, you are right. I think I forgot to mention `when place at start`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Different regex engines will treat `[^]` differently. Some will assume that it's the beginning of a negative character class excluding `]` and any characters up to the next `]` in the pattern, (e.g. `[^][]` will match anything except `]` and `[`). Other engines will treat as a empty negative character class (which will match anything). This is why some regex engines will work, and others report it as an error.

If you meant for it to match a literal `^` character, you'll have to escape it like this:

```
(jump *[A-Z].*)(?:[\^])*?([A-Z].*:)
```

Or better yet, just remove it from the character class (you'll still have to escape it because `^` has special meaning outside of a character class, too):

```
(jump *[A-Z].*)(?:\^)*?([A-Z].*:)
```

Or if you meant for it to match everything up to the next `[A-Z].*:`, try a character class like this:

```
(jump *[A-Z].*)(?:[\s\S])*?([A-Z].*:)
```

And of course, because this is Java, don't forget that you'll need to escape the all the `\` characters in any string literals.

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems here in use of `[^]`:

```
(jump *[A-Z].*)(?:[^])*?([A-Z].*:)
                   ^
-------------------|
```

Try this regex instead:

```
(jump *[A-Z].*)[\\s\\S]*?([A-Z].*:)
```

OR this:

```
(?s)(jump *[A-Z].*).*?([A-Z].*:)
```